# vb.net - dispose of all variables?

Tags: vb.net, memory

how can i make sure i dispose of ALL my variables and sessions when i close the application?

i already have session.abandon(), but does it still keep all the other objects stored somewhere in the memory?

i've noticed that my w3wp.exe process keeps going up as i am testing my application. what is a good way to keep mem usage under control?

Comment: `Session.Abandon()` sounds like asp.net. Is it?

Answer (score 1):

When the process exits, all the memory it was using goes away. You don't have to worry about it.

Comment: So why do we have to call `Object.`**`Dispose()` every time we finish using a disposable object then if it will all be cleared when the program closes?

Comment: `IDisposable.Dispose()` has nothing to do with freeing memory. It has to do with freeing things like operating system handles, etc. It allows them to be freed as soon as they are no longer needed, rather than waiting until the process exits. This is especially important if such resources are created in a loop, on a timer, etc.